# Override ActiveRecord attribute methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, activerecord

An example of what I'm talking about:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name=(name)
    super(name.capitalize)
  end
  def name
    super().downcase  # not sure why you'd do this; this is just an example
  end
end
```

This seems to work, but I was just read the section on overriding attribute methods in the [ActiveRecord::Base docs](http://rails.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), and it suggests using the `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` methods. I thought there must be something wrong with what I'm doing in the example above; otherwise, why would they bless these methods as the "right way" to override attribute methods? They're also forcing a much uglier idiom, so there must be a good reason...

My real question: Is there something wrong with this example?

Answer (score 215):

Echoing Gareth's comments... your code will not work as written. It should be rewritten this way:

```
def name=(name)
  write_attribute(:name, name.capitalize)
end

def name
  read_attribute(:name).downcase  # No test for nil?
end
```

Comment: This is no longer true.  Either super or this works now.  I've not tested the hash notation, however.

Comment: In rails 3, the reader method specified here by Aaron works, but the writer that the original poster specified (feeding the name to super) works fine, and IMHO is cleaner than manually writing the attribute as Aaron suggests.

Comment: I have tested the hash method given by mipadi below and it works like a charm (Rails v 3.2.6)

Comment: Isn't it the right answer? Thanks @Aaron, worked for me as well.

Comment: FYI, the [Rails Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) (unofficial community guide, but ~5500 stars) has [encouraged `self[:attr]` over `read_attribute(:attr)` since early 2013](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide/commit/8de8a73fadcbfd49edd239d3d4e4216eb6796577#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R278).

Comment: Still valid for rails 6, see [docu](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read/read_attribute)

Comment: This was removed in Rails 6.1: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e14e78bf447fbe1420d87212e833535a72783cd2

Answer (score 96):

As an extension to Aaron Longwell's answer, you can also use a "hash notation" to access attributes that have overridden accessors and mutators:

```
def name=(name)
  self[:name] = name.capitalize
end

def name
  self[:name].downcase
end
```

Comment: Hash notation may work, but `self.attribute` blows the stack on 3.2.16.

Comment: This has the advantage that it supports `||=` for defaulting: `def name; self[:name] ||= 'anon'; end`

Comment: For me, this hash notation works. But I don't know the reason why it works. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 7):

There is some great information available on this topic at http://errtheblog.com/posts/18-accessor-missing.

The long and short of it is that ActiveRecord does correctly handle super calls for ActiveRecord attribute accessors.

Answer (score -3):

I have a rails plugin that makes attribute overriding work with super as you would expect. You can find it on [github](http://github.com/chriseppstein/has_overrides).

To install:

```
./script/plugin install git://github.com/chriseppstein/has_overrides.git
```

To use:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_overrides

  module Overrides
    # put your getter and setter overrides in this module.
    def title=(t)
      super(t.titleize)
    end
  end
end
```

Once you've done that things just work:

```
$ ./script/console 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.2)
>> post = Post.new(:title => "a simple title")
=> #<Post id: nil, title: "A Simple Title", body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> post.title = "another simple title"
=> "another simple title"
>> post.title
=> "Another Simple Title"
>> post.update_attributes(:title => "updated title")
=> true
>> post.title
=> "Updated Title"
>> post.update_attribute(:title, "singly updated title")
=> true
>> post.title
=> "Singly Updated Title"
```