# "stack level too deep error" on every change of routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

Everytime I change my routes.rb I get a "stack level too deep error" on any first request and afterwards I get a "routing error" until I restart my development server. After a restart everything works like a charm.

The trace says the following:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70

Rendered /Users/timo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered /Users/timo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered /Users/timo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.6ms)
```

Unfortunately I can't retrace when this problem started to occur, after which update or code change or so. All I know is, it started to happen lately and it happend with rails 3.2.8 and mri 1.9.3-p125 which I updated to rails 3.2.9 and mri 1.9.3-p327 without effect.

This is actually only annoying (as it works after a restart) but help is still appreciated!

Comment: Please include your routes.rb file.

Comment: Updating to devise 2.2.1 solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from an earlier version of OP's post:

> I was able to find the culprit: DEVISE!   When I comment the
>   following lines everything works fine.
>
> ```
> devise_for :listeners, :controllers => {:registrations => "listeners/registrations", :invitations => "listeners/invitations"}, :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
> devise_scope :listener do
>   get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
> end
> ```
>
> Now I also know that this issue is a duplicate with:
>   [rails 3 routes stack level too deep devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919070/rails-3-routes-stack-level-too-deep-devise)