# Rails display American date format when using Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I'm trying to use the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464793/what-is-the-right-way-to-override-a-setter-method-in-ruby-on-rails) to convert my date format in my model. The reason I am doing this is I want my user to see the date format as 7/20/2014, but I need to save that date into the database as 2014-7-20. I tried to implement that with this code, but it is not changing the date format when creating or reading:

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def date_requested
        read_attribute(:date_requested).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    end

    def date_requested=(date_requested)
        write_attribute(:date_requested, date_requested.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you using a datepicker?? like [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)??

Comment: Yes I'm using bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: Honestly I'm just looking for the best way to use datepicker and display m/d/year, but save to the database in the expected format. When editing forms I want to display in m/d/year as well.

Comment: Can you show the params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. Here's what I did to use American style dates with Bootstrap datepicker:

1. Add the gem [american_date](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date) to your gemfile: gem 'american_date'. This gem parses a date as m/d/yy into the format required by the database.
2. Run bundle install in terminal
3. Set your form field to show a value rather than what is actually in the database:

   ```
     <%= f.text_field :requested_date, :value => @inquiry.requested_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %>
   ```
4. Edit your index or show file to display the American format: <%= @inquiry.requested_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>

This is working great for me.