# How to get current value of attribute before saving new one in AR?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with such attributes:

1. `some_number`
2. `some_string`

I want to put some value in `some_string` depending on current value of `some_number` and new value of `some_number` on updating.

Example:

Current `some_number` is **4**

New (updated) value of `some_number` is **5**

I want to put `4+5` string into `some_string` before `some_number` is overwritten.

How can I get it worked?

Comment: Override the `some_number=` setter -- cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464793/what-is-the-right-way-to-override-a-setter-method-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Could you please explain me a bit more clearly how can I solve my problem by overriding a setter?
How can I get current value and new value in that setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I would need to modify some attribute depending on other attribute value on update event I'd do like that:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_update :modify_some_string
    protected
    def modify_some_string
            # some actions with self.some_string and self.some_number
            # and self.some_string_was and self.some_number_was
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from your question as stated, but assuming you want `some_number`'s current value at the end of `some_string`...

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initiaize
    @numbers = []
    super
  end

  def some_number=(value)
    @numbers << value
    write_attribute :some_string, @numbers.join('+')
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this solution applies to every change to `some_number`, independent of whether or not the model is `save`d to the database.