# Rails autopopulates form with database values thus ignoring my model methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, auto-populate

**My view:**

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :hi %>
<% end %>
```

**My model:**

```
def hi
  'hello'
end
```

Which works properly from console - no matter what `:hi` attribute really is in the database, it's retrieved as `'hello'`.

I guess Rails ignores model method overrides when autopopulating forms?
How do I make it pay attention to my override?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10465235/326543) help?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan, no, I'm doing it properly. If I check `hi`'s value with `<%= hi %>` in my views, I'll get `'hello'` just as expected.

Comment: No, the way that it works is that rails supplies a "get" and "set" method for every db field, ie "def hi" and "def hi=(s)".  If you override these in your model then it will use the version from your model.  What i suspect is that you haven't defined it properly.  Can you add the code for the Product class to your question?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I think it does use my getter, since when I put `<%= hi %>` in my view, it displays `'hello'`.

Comment: `hi` alone in the view wouldn't call the model method.  have you actually just defined a helper method?  it's only a helper that you could call standalone in the view like that.

Comment: There's no "hi" method in your Product model, in that repo.  https://github.com/lakesare/edit_form/blob/master/app/models/product.rb

Comment: @MaxWilliams,  I put <%= hi %> in my view ----- typo again, sorry! I meant `@product.hi`.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, in that repo hi == name. When edit form is saved, it does call `def hi=(value) ... end` method. I concluded it also calls getter methods from my model when autopopulating the form, I guess it itsn't the case?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, yes, seems not to be the case according to evgeny petriv's answer.

Comment: Argh, why don't you copy and paste your code instead of retyping it, then you won't have typos?  This sort of thing adds a massive layer of confusion.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I tried to make it simpler:-( I'll pay more attention to it.

Comment: Why are you referring to a method called "hi" when your method is called "name"?  This is another thing which just adds confusion.  You are saying "please look at my repo, where the method names are different to the ones i've asked about". Can't you see that that is really confusing?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, yep, must be, that was a bad choice of names in that test repo. Usually I just keep them as short and different as I can, didn't think of it being easier to grasp if I keep them the same, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails gets [contents of the textarea](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_area.rb#L13) from `#attributes[:hi].value_before_typecast`, so to get content to be filed from `product.hi`  you should use [content_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)

Comment: oh I'm really sorry, this is a typo, fixed it.

Comment: So this does not create `<textarea name=product[hello] ...`?

Comment: no, it creates `<textarea name=product[hi]...` just as it should. But it populates my textarea with real value of `hi` attribute instead of populating it with the value provided by me.

Comment: ugh. okay, strange behaviour, thank you, that is the answer I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, in place of

```
  <%= f.text_area :hi %>
```

Add:

```
<%= @model_name.hi%>
```

It works.

Comment: It wasn't my aim to display value I want