# Rails - Humanize attribute globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, human-readable

Let's say I have a `User` model with a `name` attribute. If a `@user` has name `'CAIO'` I can call the humanize method to make it nicer:

```
@user.name          =======> CAIO
@user.name.humanize =======> Caio
```

But I'm lazy and I don't want to call `humanize` every time: I would like `@user.name` to return the humanized version.

Now, I know that I could do it with a helper method or a model one like

```
def h_name
  self.name.humanize
end
```

but doing like this then I have to change all the `@user.name` in my app with `@user.h_name`... and I'm lazy!!! :-)

Isn't there a way to declare it directly in the model, but using `name` to call it? Even better it would be something working for the `name` of all my models!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper). This gem provides decorators (much like presenters) which bundles view logic in an object oriented fashion. Also, Ryan Bates has put together an excellent [RailsCast on Draper](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper).

Comment: I checked, and I suggest everybody to give Draper a try. It's really handy!

Answer (score 1):

You can add before_save in model.

before_save :h_name

def h_name
    self.name = self.name.humanize
  end

Answer (score 1):

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373731/override-activerecord-attribute-methods) explains several ways to do this.

One possibility is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def name
        super().humanize
    end
end
```