# Treat a model attribute as a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model has a string field (a short) and it stores it in db which is **fine**. But I want it always to **return** a symbol instead of string and, also, I'd like to assign a symbol to this string attribute. What I'm doing now doesn't work.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attr1

  def attr1
    # self.try(:attr1).to_sym # how to return symbol?
  end

  def attr1= value
   #    super.attr1.to_sym # doesn't work either
  end
end
```

How do I reach this?

Comment: What sort of data does the column store?

Comment: Why do you want to assign a symbol to the attribute?  The database won't save it as a symbol.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, I need it. You better read my question again.

Comment: Your question doesn't answer my question of why you want to assign a symbol to the attribute.  At any rate, the default setter already lets you do this.  Given you have `attr_accessible :attr1` you can set `attr1` to anything: `my_model.attr1 = :symbol` works, as does `my_model.attr1 = 200`, as does `my_model.attr1 = "string"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [override ActiveRecord attribute methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373731/override-activerecord-attribute-methods)

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta - suppose you have an attribute that holds one of a limited number of values, for example, a 'state' attribute. Aside from the details of the persistence mechanism (the database), this is a case where you'd typically use a symbol in ruby. And if your ruby code is going to do some computation with those state values (store them, compare them, use them as hash keys, whatever) then the cost of converting to a symbol upon load may be being able to do fast comparisons in later operations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you only need to overwrite the getter, the setter probably works fine if it is a field.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base  
  def attr1
    attributes['attr1']&.to_sym
  end
end
```

Or you could also create a Serializer:

```
class SymbolSerializer
  def self.dump(obj)
    return unless obj
    obj.to_s
  end

  def self.load(text)
    return unless text
    text.to_sym
  end
end
```

And then in your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :attr1, SymbolSerializer
end
```

Comment: @MariusKavansky the values will be stored as strings because DB has no concept of symbols. strings will be converted to symbols after they have been read.

Comment: I would add one small improvement to this to cover the scenario when the attribute is nil: `self.attributes['attr1'].try(:to_sym)`

Comment: This is still the perfect way to do this.  My "attr1" is now used as a symbol in every way, and I love it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do it on multiple columns or in different models I would suggest to generalize the solution:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base  
  include Concerns::Columnable

  treat_as_symbols :attr1
end

module Concerns::Columnable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.treat_as_symbols *args
      args.each do |column|
        define_method "#{column}" do
          read_attribute(column.to_sym).to_sym
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: would recommend `read_attribute(column.to_sym).try(:to_sym)` to handle: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

I liked both of the current answers, but there are some pros and cons to both.

### Serializer vs define_method

When you do the `define_method` approach you only override the getter so when you look at the object you will see the original value, this is a departure from other value modifiers like `enums` and `serializers`, hence my preference of the `serializer` in my following solution. You may like the more minimal manipulation in your implementation.

```rb
instance = MyModel.new(attr1: "string")

instance            # => #<MyModel:0x0000ffffacaa19d0 id: 1, attr1: "string">
# the getter only works here
instance.attr1      # => :string
instance.inspect    # => "#<MyModel id: 1, attr1: "string">"
instance.attributes # => {"id"=>1, "attr1"=>"string" }
```

### readability / maintainability

I liked the readability of not calling the `serializer` directly which can be done with abstraction like in the `Concern` approach with the `treat_attributes_as_symbol` method.  This also more DRY over sprinkling references the `SymbolSerializer` all over.

### [Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) / cherry pick models vs [ApplicationRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models) / every model

There are advantages of `Concerns`, but I want to use this widely enough I made it available for every Model, so I chose to implement it in my `ApplicationRecord`

I merged the two approaches as follows:

1. I created the SymbolSerializer
2. In my `ApplicationRecord` I implemented a method like the `Concern` logic did:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def treat_attributes_as_symbol(*attributes_to_symbolize)
      attributes_to_symbolize.each do |attribute_to_symbolize|
        serialize(attribute_to_symbolize, SymbolSerializer)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

3. now I can call `treat_attributes_as_symbol` in my models:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  treat_attributes_as_symbol :attr1
end
```

4. everyone gets a symbol:

```rb
instance = MyModel.new(attr1: "string")

instance            # => #<MyModel:0x0000ffffacaa19d0 id: 1, attr1: :string>
instance.attr1      # => :string
instance.inspect    # => "#<MyModel id: 1, attr1: :string>"
instance.attributes # => {"id"=>1, "attr1"=>:string }
```