# Is it possible to format data as it comes out of the database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, overloading

In rails I have data already in my database.  I would like for certain things to be formatted certain ways no matter where it displays in my app.  An example might be a social security number.  In the database it might be stored as 123456789, but I want to display it as 123-45-6789 anywhere it shows up.

I know that I can format the output using string manipulation, but I wanted to know if there was a better way so that if I were to use,

```
<%= user.ssn %>
```

It would automatically get formatted correctly.

#### Update:

After much, MUCH research on my part, I came across the "lazy" way. You can override the default getter using the following in the User model.

```
def ssn
  read_attribute(:ssn).insert(5, '-').insert(3, '-')
end
```

My utter ignorance of proper terminology prevented me from finding this more easily. This sort of the is referred to as overriding a method and is discussed in the Rails documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

All that being said I'll be writing a helper method which I originally thought of, but wanted to see if there was an easier way (i.e. less code writing).  In the process I learned a lot about ActiveRecord, so my time not wasted.  :-)

Other references:

- [What is the right way to override a setter method in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464793/what-is-the-right-way-to-override-a-setter-method-in-ruby-on-rails)
- [Override ActiveRecord attribute methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373731/override-activerecord-attribute-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach is to create an [Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html).

```
def format_ssn(value)
  # apply the transformation
end

<%= format_ssn(user.ssn) %>
```

If you want the value to always be outputted in that way, you can also consider to provide an alternative method in the model

```
class User
  def formatted_ssn
    # transform and return user.ssn
  end
end
```

You may see examples of people overriding the getter of `ssn` to properly format the value, but I strongly suggest you to avoid that approach. It may cause the formatted value to be stored in the database, overriding the original one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This app is only going to be dealing with archived data, so I won't be writing to the database, but I'm going to take your advice anyway. This will be helpful to me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be something like what Richard said where you manipulate in some sort of ViewModel/PageObject/Decorator/Blahblah. The Rails way would be to use a helper method. The lazy way is to override your `ssn` getter in the User model to format `super`

Now you need to decide what kind of developer you are :]

Comment: I ultimately chose the helper method way as my answer, but I found this answer to be the most helpful in my growth as a developer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a view model. A bit like a presenter which is often done to add presentation logic, but which speaks the language of the view, a view model talks the language of the model but is just a simple decorator.

Instead of just passing an instance of user

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

You would do something like

```
user = User.find(params[:id]
@user = UserView.new(user)
```

When I use a View Model it's usually a PORO decorate adding a few methods or overriding methods on User.

Here's a sample from a real application of mine, adapted to your question:

```
class ViewModelBase < SimpleDelegator

  def self.view_for(name)
    define_method(name) { __getobj__ }
  end

  def class
    __getobj__.class
  end
end


class UserView < ViewModelBase
  view_for :user

  def formatted_ssn
    formatting_rules(user.ssn)
  end

  def formatting_rules(ssn)
    # some rules for formatting an ssn
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, just wow. I'm new to Rails and haven't heard of this approach yet. I will have to look into this some more.  Thanks for the education.