# ruby syntax (rails models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone explain the difference between these two:

Say I have a model Product

inside that model I have:

```
self.price
self[:price]
```

I'm assuming one calls an attribute (the products price), while the other calls a method named 'price'?

If that's true, which is which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails creates those model attributes as accessors which dynamically creates the methods for getting/setting the value. Its fun to use in your own classes as well, have a look here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor

Comment: So if I create my own method with the same name as an attribute, my method gets called not the rails default?

Comment: Here's a post that details how you might want to accomplish that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373731/override-activerecord-attribute-methods

Answer (score 4):

Both calling a method:

- first one calls a method `:price`.
- second one calls a method `:[]`, passing `:price` as an argument.

You can check that by running

```
self.method(:[])
#=> #<Method: User(ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods)#[]>
```

Basically anytime you want to know, where method comes from, you can use [Object#`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-method).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.